# Dependence on Keyed Hash Function

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

I'm reading the paper “[Collision-Resistant Hashing? Towards Making UOWHFs Practical](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/tcr-hash.pdf)” which states:

> With an ACR hash function $F$ the key $K$ is announced and the adversary wins if she manages to any collision $M,M'$ for $f = F_K$. The points $M$ and $M'$ may depend arbitrarily on $K$.

Could you give me an example of messages $M$ and $M'$, so that they depend arbitrarily on $K$?

<sub>My other questions related to the same paper:

[Dependence on Keyed Hash Function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11631/dependence-on-keyed-hash-function) • [No Birthday Attack to TCR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11633/no-birthday-attack-to-tcr) • [Weaker Notion of Target Collision Resistance](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11632/weaker-notion-of-target-collision-resistance)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $F_K(x)$ = $M \bmod K$.

Then after $K$ is announced choose arbitrary $M$ and compute $M' = M + K$.